# Index-out-of-bounds error on GUI

Tags: python, user-interface

A friend and I constantly receive an Index Out-of-bounds error when trying to create a GUI with a range of entries into a list:

```
df = pandas.DataFrame(columns = list(self.workingData.columns))
ser = selectSpecies.isin(self.workingData["Species"])
for x in range((len(self.workingData.index))):
if(ser.iloc[x]): #Keeps getting index out of bounds error df =    
df.append(self.workingData.iloc[x,:])
```

We have tried different indices on ser.iloc[x], including x - 1 and x + 1, to no avail. How and why is this error getting provoked?

Comment: It seems `workingData` is larger than `ser`. You might try adding a `print` statement to see where the loop stops.

Comment: Good idea. We're going to try that straightaway.

Comment: what is the return type of `.isin()`? Try printing the value of `self.workingData.index` and check if `ser.iloc[]` has max index more than or equal to that

Comment: It is a series of booleans rather than a single one...

Comment: Trying printing out `len(self.workingData.index)` and `len(ser.iloc)`